# Random position of fading list items

Tags: jquery, random, position, fading

This code fades list items in and out nicely. But I'd like the list items to be positioned randomly within a div

```
$(function () {
    var list_slideshow = $("#site_slideshow_inner_text"),
        listItems = list_slideshow.children('li'),
        listLen = listItems.length,
        i = 0,
        changeList = function () {
            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(300, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(300);
            });
        };
    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(changeList, 1000);
});
```

What can I add to this to get random positioning?

Comment: It depends 100% on how you are positioning them now. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started, you need to provide more info in the question to get a better answer, ie. what you've tried with code examples.

```
$('li').each(function(){
var randomTop = $('div').height()*Math.random(); //random top position
var randomLeft = $('div').width()*Math.random(); //random left position

$(this).css({ //apply the position each li
        top        : randomTop,
        left    : randomLeft
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sionnach733/78w6M/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I've go it working pretty well here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/78w6M/18/) but I am finding some of the list items break out of the box. Is there a way I can keep the whole list item within the container?

Comment: I added some padding to `li` and accounted for the height and width of the `li` when calculating the random positions, that should do the trick. see http://jsfiddle.net/78w6M/21/

Comment: did that work? if so, consider accepting this answer.

Comment: It did work and marked as Solved. Very sorry for the very late reply.